# When I pass functor to thread destructor is called

Tags: c++11

I have to run thread in c++11 with functor Runner

```
class Runner {
public:
Runner(int){create toData on heap;}
~Runner(){delete toData;}

void operator()()const{
 loop();

}


private:

pointer* toData;

};
```

and when I try to run thread like

```
Runner temp(1);
thread(temp);
```

or

```
thread(move(temp));
```

destructor is called and deleted data and get segmentation fault.
How to avoid this ?

Comment: What is the prototype for thread()?

Comment: Probably you're calling `thread` with the parameter passed by value, it copies the object (which does not have a copy constructor, same probably if you call it using `std::move` and you don't define the move constructor), and at the end of the thread it destroys the copied one and invalidates the pointer. Then, when the program ends, it invokes the destructor again, but the pointer was already invalidated. As @PaolaJ said, post the `thread` prototype.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you written correct copy or move-copy constructors and operators?

Comment: Yeah that's probably the cause

Comment: why are so many people storing raw pointers in their classes? <sigh>

Comment: @RichardHodges What to store, I don't have lot of experience with c++.

Comment: look up the documentation on unique_ptr, auto_ptr and shared_ptr. (do a google search). Also read any book by Herb Sutter, andrei alexandrescu or bjarne stroustrup. Prepare yourself. It will take you 2 years to learn to become fluent with c++ but these guys will point you in the right direction.